# Exclude first (or last) in Rails "each"

Tags: ruby-on-rails

How do I exclude the first and/or last item in the Rails each:

```
<% @shops.each_with_index do |shop, i| %>
  ... some code ...
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Use a range to slice the array before invoking `each_with_index`:

If you want to exclude the first element, start from `1`.

To exclude the last element, end at `-2`.

```
@shops[1..-2].each_with_index do |shop, i| 
   ...
end
```

Comment: Thanks. I refine my question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4283642/exclude-if-same-item-in-rails

Answer (score 2):

if your @shops array is not very big, you can slice it before doing the loop:

```
@shops[1..-2].each_with_index do |shop, i|
```

the above is to exclude both the first and last... you can start with 0 to include the first, or use -1 at the end to include the last.

Comment: Thanks. I refine my question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4283642/exclude-if-same-item-in-rails