# Exclude if same item in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

In my `Shop` (name = ABC; ID = 10) show view, I want to show the nearby shops. Hence, I use this:

```
          <h1>
            Shops nearby <span id="title"><%=h @shop.name %></span>
          </h1>

<% @shops.each_with_index do |shop, i| %>
                    <% if shop.geocoded? %>
                    {
                      latitude: <%= shop.lat %>,
                    longitude: <%= shop.lng %>,
                      html: "<a href='#item_<%= i + 1 %>'><strong><%=h shop.name %></strong></a>",
                      icon: { image: "<%= APP_CONFIG[:site_url] + '/images/map_blue_' + (i+1).to_s + '.png' %>",
                              iconsize: [48, 48],
                              iconanchor: [24,48],
                              infowindowanchor: [24, 0] }
                    },
                    <% end %>
                  <% end %>
```

You will notice that the `h1` actually shows the current shop ABC, and the rest of `each` actually shows all the shops nearby it. The problem is, it also includes the shop ABC as it is the nearest point. How do I ask the `each` to exclude shop ABC?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use [`reject`](http://ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Array.html#M002196):

```
other_shops = @shops.reject {|shop| shop == @shop}
```

Then iterate over `other_shops`:

```
other_shops.each_with_index do |shop, i|
  ...
```

Answer (score 2):

When you set @shops in the first place, use an extra condition `"id <> ?", shop.id`