# Rails: .each do EXCEPT

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have this code in my app

```
<% foos.each |f| %>

   <% f.user.foos.each |f| %>
     // How do you show all the foos except the foo above?
   <% end %>

<% end %>
```

How do you show all the foos except the "foo" above?

---

I'm not trying to remove the first element. I'm trying to remove just that "foo"

Comment: possible duplicate of [Exclude first (or last) in Rails "each"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4283443/exclude-first-or-last-in-rails-each)

Comment: You need a 'do' before |f| to have this work

Comment: @jcm I'm not trying to remove the first element. I'm trying to remove just that "foo"

Comment: Which is that "foo"? Also you have used `f` as a variable name twice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
foos.drop(0).each do |f|
  f.do_something
end
```

The code removes the first element of this Array and then iterate.

Pay attention if your `foos` is not an Array but a ActiveRecord::Relation object(aka, scope). This code will not work. In that case it's better to provide correct collection from query directly.

**Update** Noticed OP actually need modification on nested loop.

The second "each" loop has a smell, the `foos` hand is too long to manage User's stuff. Let's refactor and use a better example. Say you need to list all articles, within each article you need to list the author's articles except the current one.

```
class Article < ActiveRecord::Base

  def author_other_articles
    user.other_articles(self)
  end
end

class User < ActiveRecord::Base

  def other_articles(article)
    self.articles.where.not(id: article.id)
  end

end

# View

<%= @articles.each do |article| %>
  <h2><%= article.title %></h2>
  <%= article.authoer_other_articles do |a| %>
    <h3><%= a.title %></h3>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: I'm not trying to remove the first element. I'm trying to remove just that "foo"

Answer (score 0):

your code is a little confusing since you're using the same variable `f` in both your loops but I think I know what you want to achieve

```
>> (1..5).each do |num1|
>>   (1..5).each do |num2|
>>    next if num2 == num1
>>    print num2
>>  end
>>  puts ''
>> end

2345
1345
1245
1235
1234
```

basically, all you need to do is add a check inside the second loop if the foo there is equal to the foo in the outer loop. also, use different variables for each loop.

Answer (score 0):

Try using `select`:

```
<% foos.each |foo| %>
  <% foo.user.foos.select{ |f| f != foo }.each |inner_foo| %>
    // do stuff with inner_foo
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

[Ruby `Enumerable` docs](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-select)

Comment: this isn't a good idea.  if `foo.user.foos` returns a big array, you're looping through a big array twice.

Comment: Fair comment. @Jon will have to weight the pros and cons of that for himself.

Comment: @jvnill this isn't tit-for-tat or anything like that, but how is your answer different?  It loops through the array twice as well.

Comment: ah no it doesn't. `foo.user.foos.select{ |f| f != foo }.each` this loops through `foo.user.foos` twice because you have to select which `foo` is not equal to `f` first then you go through `each`.  my solution goes to `each` directly then just skips if foo is equal to f.